# Set selected index in Razor drop down list using Java Script

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor, getelementbyid

In my project I have three objects: Invoice, InvoiceItem and PaymentMethod. Invoice contains lists of InvoiceItems and PaymentMethods (Master with 2 Details). For InvoiceItem and Payament method I have 2 partial view that are loading on Create, Edit and Details page. When I am reading data from database, all the data is as expected expect for DropDowns. I am not able to set SelectedIndex in drop downs as expected. InvoiceItems partial view has 2 drop downs (Customer and Transport). PaymentMethod partial view has one drop down (PaymentMethodDetails). Note: When I read data into  EditorFor instead of DropDown, everything is as expected. But when I try to set selected values from model into database, values are set correctly only for the first dropdown (Customer), other two drop downs have first item as selected (value is not selected).

**InvoiceItem partial view**

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 1px">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerId, "CustomerId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-lg-2" })
                <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-left: 30px">
                    @Html.DropDownList("CustomerId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = Model.RbrStavke, @style = "width: 140px" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 1px">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TransportId, "TransportId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-lg-2" })
                <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-left: 30px">
                    @Html.DropDownList("TransportId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = Model.RbrStavke, @style = "width: 100px" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

**PaymentMethod partial view**

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 1px">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PaymentMethodId, "PaymentMethodId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-lg-2" })
    <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-left: 40px">
        @Html.DropDownList("PaymentMethodId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = Model.IDNacinaPlacanja, @style = "width: 200px" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit Invoice view (loads two partial views)**

```
    <ul class="list-group" id="ii">

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.InvoiceItems.Count(); i++)
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.InvoiceItems[i], "InvoiceItems")
        }
    </ul>

    <ul class="list-group" id="pm">

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PaymentMethods.Count(); i++)
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.PaymentMethods[i], "PaymentMethods")
        }
    </ul>
```

**Java Script in Edit Invoice view**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                    var invoiceItem = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.InvoiceItems.Select(x => new
                    {
                        ItemId = x.ItemId,
                        CustomerId = x.CustomerId,
                        TransportId = x.TransportId
                    })));

                    var paymentMethod = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PaymentMethods.Select(x => new
                    {
                        PaymentMethodId = x.PaymentMethodId
                    })));

                    for (var i = 0; i < invoiceItem.length; i++)
                    {
                        var id = invoiceItem[i].ItemId;
                        var c = invoiceItem[i].CustomerId;
                        var t = invoiceItem[i].TransportId;

                        document.getElementById(id).selectedIndex = c - 1;
                        //todo: set selected paymentmethod 

                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i < paymentMethod.length; i++)
                    {
                        var idPm = paymentMethod[i].PaymentMethodId;
                        //todo: set selected paymentmethod 
                    }

                }, false);
```

This works for CustomerId selected item in the dropdown. When I do the same for Transport and PaymentMethod (document.getElementById) it does not work.

How can I change this so that other two drop downs have correct selected value from the model?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set selected item for dropdownlist in js.You can try to use like:

```
$("#{idOfDropDown}").val("selectedvalue");
```

`id` should be unique,so don't use `@id = Model.RbrStavke` for different dropdowns,and `{idOfDropDown}` should be the id value of the dropdown which you want to set.